# How to get image processed count with group by clause?

Tags: sql-server

I have table `JobInfo` which contains columns JobId, ImageId, StatusId

Requrired result : 
I need to know how many images are processed. For processed images, value of `StatusId` is `7`

Below query is displaying only those jobIds for which `statusId=7` exits, but I need all jobIds.

If statusid is not present for particular jobid then count should be 0 corresponding to that jobid.

SQL QUERY

```
 SELECT  jobid,COUNT(imageid) AS 'ProcessedCount'
 FROM    JobInfo WITH ( NOLOCK )
 WHERE   statusid = 7
 GROUP BY JobId ORDER BY JobId
```

How to achieve this result?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the where clause ... and just execute as below .... Using sum and case statement you can get your expected result...

```
SELECT  jobid,
        COUNT(imageid) As TotalCount, 
        Sum(Case when Statusid=7 then 1 else 0 end)  AS 'ProcessedCount'
FROM    JobInfo WITH ( NOLOCK )
-- WHERE   statusid = 7
GROUP BY JobId ORDER BY JobId
```

Comment: There are multiple statusIDs (5,-5,7,9). I need count for only statusId=7

Comment: You said "Below query is displaying only those jobIds for which statusId=7 exists, but I need all jobIds" clearly selecting all regardless of their status! How can you say now that you need a count for only statusId = 7? Have you run the query?

Comment: Please be calm friend, your updated query is working fine.
Thank you !! :)